# Win32 C++ Using Multimedia Timers

Tags: c++, winapi, timer

I have been working on a program to keep times for multiple items. I've been using the WM_TIMER and recently noticed it is running

way too slow. So I have been trying to get a multimedia timer working.

The problem is it will display partially some of the window, leaving transparent rectangles where my owner drawn controls sit. At

the same time, I get an error: the program has quit working.

From examples I found online, pretty much the same thing happened.

Globally I have this variable:

```
PHANDLE ptrTimerHandle;
```

MSDN, if I read correctly, says you can rename the callback function.

```
VOID CALLBACK TimerCallback(PVOID lpParameter, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired);
```

Here is how I try to set the timer in WinMain (going for 500ms until it starts, and ticks every 200ms):

```
CreateTimerQueueTimer(ptrTimerHandle, NULL, TimerCallback, 0, 500, 200, WT_EXECUTEDEFAULT | WT_EXECUTEINTIMERTHREAD);
```

Then the function, thats empty, but I did test and nothing is ever sent to it.

```
VOID CALLBACK TimerCallback(PVOID lpParameter, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired) {}
```

Before trying to do this, I copied and pasted an example from MSDN that I also could not get to work. Same problems as above.

I have included the correct libraries, and included the right files, and it compiles perfectly fine.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you try the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687003(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What are you doing while you are waiting for the timer?

Comment: Yeah, thats actually the one I copy and pasted. I am using wxDevC++ to compile. I was a bit unsure how to get parts to work. I compiled first as a console program, could not figure out the printf's, commented them all out and used cout instead. Then I compiled, no errors, right includes and libraries. No window pops up but the program did run, right until about 10 sec and it was done. The console window never popped up, either.

Comment: Also, `WT_EXECUTEDEFAULT | WT_EXECUTEINTIMERTHREAD` is a conflict. The first tells it to queue the function to a non-IO thread, while the second tells it to execute it directly on the timer thread.

Comment: I have two windows. The main one is always shown, it uses the timer to update an int by 50ms for each call. Then there is a function that updates the time values. I recently added an animated gradient for the second window. Every 50ms from the main window, I send a timer message to the second, which updates R,G,B values, and updates the gradient. That is where I really noticed the timers lagging. From the task manager the program keeps a constant ~650kb memory, and its CPU useage never goes above 0. (in normal use)

Comment: I just changed around the WT_s, program still stops working as soon as it shows.

Comment: You probably don't want to execute in the timer thread, get it to spawn a new thread on timeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing the following before (or after, I forget) including `windows.h`:

```
#define  _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601 // value for windows 7
```

Since Queue timers don't work unless this value is greater than 0x0500. I've had this happen before when visual studio decided that I wasn't running on windows 7 for some reason.

Here is the [Page that tells you about this in remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Here is the [documentation for windows versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

The following code works for me:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void __stdcall 
TimerCallback(PVOID lpParameter, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    HANDLE ptrTimerHandle;
    CreateTimerQueueTimer(&ptrTimerHandle, NULL, TimerCallback, NULL, 500, 200, WT_EXECUTEDEFAULT );

    getchar();

    DeleteTimerQueueTimer(NULL, ptrTimerHandle, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I suspect the reason your program is not working properly is because you use `PHANDLE` instead of `HANDLE`.
Which will get you a access exception since you never initialise the `PHANDLE` to hold a `HANDLE`.
If you notice, I use a `HANDLE` and then pass the reference to that `HANDLE` into the function which does not cause an access exception.